# FullCalendar: how to create custom time slots?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3, timeslots

I need custom time slots for my FullCalendar app. Instead of hourly slots, I need slots that last from 09.00 to 13.00 (4hours), from 13.00 to 18.00 (5hours) and from 18.00 to 22.00(4hours).

[image]

This is an issue that has been fixed as described [here](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/pull/238), but the solution doesn't seem to work in my case:

```
slotLabelFormat: 'H:mm',
timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
slots: [{start: '09:00', end: '13:00'},{start: '13:00', end: '18:00'}, {start: '18:00', end: '22:00'}]
```

Using this code, the slots still appear hourly... I am using Fullcalendar 3.9

Comment: It's impossible to create slots of unequal duration with fullCalendar as it currently stands. Perhaps you could submit a feature request to the people who maintain it (if no similar one exists already). See https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features

Comment: P.S. I don't see where in the link you provided it says it was fixed? The thread was closed without the pull request being accepted. Whatever it contained was not merged into fullCalendar. In the last entry you can see it was then linked to another issue https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/472 which is still open.